# unexpected typescript this is undefined type

Tags: typescript

```
    /// <reference path="../typings/signalr/signalr.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

interface IMyBlackjack {

}

module My {
    export class MyBlackjack implements IMyBlackjack {

        private hub: HubProxy;
        private cnn: HubConnection;

        constructor() {
            $("#formBlackJack").hide();

            this.cnn = $.hubConnection();
            this.hub = this.cnn.createHubProxy("blackjackHub");
            this.cnn.start(() => this.onConnStart);
        }

        private onConnStart(): void {
            $("#formBlackJack").show();
            this.hub.invoke('hello');
        }
    }
}

var myBlackjack: IMyBlackjack = new My.MyBlackjack();
```

there is a problem in the code:

```
this.hub.invoke('hello');
```

this.hub is surprisingly undefined.

And I hope it should be an object.
Any thoughts about it ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`this` is not pointing to the instance. Fix use a lambda:

```
    private onConnStart = () => {
        $("#formBlackJack").show();
        this.hub.invoke('hello');
    }
```

More: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA

## also

```
this.cnn.start(() => this.onConnStart);
```

perhaps you meant to `call` i.e. `() => this.onConnStart()`

Comment: Unfortunately, in your case onConnStart  callback doesn't work. So there is a problem.

Comment: thanks for this. was scratching my head before. makes sense, but it also not consistent. cheers